# Issue with DATETIME field MS-SQL in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I have the following query in MSSQL:

```
SELECT DataFeed.AccountTranID, DataFeed.Datetime as MyDT
FROM admin_all.DataFeed
where cast(DataFeed.Datetime as Date) = cast(getdate() as Date)
```

which gives the following output :

```
AccountTranID   MyDT
124552  2019-07-31 00:00:04.660
124553  2019-07-31 00:00:07.933
124554  2019-07-31 00:00:25.623
124555  2019-07-31 00:00:29.013
124556  2019-07-31 00:00:29.206
124557  2019-07-31 00:00:44.893
124558  2019-07-31 00:00:56.796
124559  2019-07-31 00:01:11.353
124560  2019-07-31 00:01:12.260
124561  2019-07-31 00:01:19.413
124562  2019-07-31 00:01:19.510
124563  2019-07-31 00:01:28.596
124564  2019-07-31 00:01:30.710
124565  2019-07-31 00:01:46.976
124566  2019-07-31 00:01:49.823
124567  2019-07-31 00:01:57.340
```

when trying to fetch the MyDT field with this PHP code, I cannot get an output (blank). With AccountTranID, no issue.

here goes the Php code:

```
$tsql = "SELECT DataFeed.AccountTranID, DataFeed.Datetime as MyDT 
FROM admin_all.DataFeed where cast(DataFeed.Datetime as Date) = cast(getdate() as Date) ";
// Executes the query
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);

// Error handling
if ($stmt === false) {
    die(formatErrors(sqlsrv_errors()));
}
?>

<h1> Results : </h1>

<?php

while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {


    echo  $row['AccountTranID'].'-'. $row['MyDT'].'<br>';

}

sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
sqlsrv_close($conn);
```

Comment: the only difference is the use of alias. Just to try do not use the alias for your second element selected

Comment: when trying with no alias "$tsql = "SELECT DataFeed.AccountTranID, DataFeed.Datetime  
FROM admin_all.DataFeed "; i still get a blank output for $row['Datetime']

Comment: try echo "<pre>"; print_r($row); after the while line

Comment: i get Array (note: this is a record not included in above table)
(
    [AccountTranID] => 18784
    [Datetime] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2019-06-29 18:46:07.257000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => UTC
        )

)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As we found out, the second selected element of the query is DateTime type, so you have to parse it to string.

You can do with this code:

```
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo  $row['AccountTranID'].'-'. $row['MyDT']->format('Y-m-d H:i:s').'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Explanations:**

When you retrieve data from SQL Server using `sqlsrv_query()`, you can control the way the `date` or `date/time` values are [returned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/how-to-retrieve-date-and-time-type-as-strings-using-the-sqlsrv-driver?view=sql-server-2017) from SQL Server. This can be done by setting `'ReturnDatesAsStrings'` option in the connection string. The default value for this option is `false` and `smalldatetime`, `datetime`, `date`, `time`, `datetime2`, and `datetimeoffset` types are returned as PHP DateTime objects. When this option is `true` these values are returned as strings.

**Retrieve `date` or `date/time` values as PHP datetime object:**

```
<?php
    // Connection
    $server = '127.0.0.1\ikosoft,1066';
    $cinfo = array(
        "ReturnDatesAsStrings"=>false,
        "Database" => "database",
        "UID" => "username",
        "PWD" => "password"
    );
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $cinfo);
    if( $conn === false )
    {
        echo "Error (sqlsrv_connect): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
        exit;
    }

    ....
    // Fetch data
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo  $row['MyDT']->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."<br>";
    }
    ...
?>
```

**Retrieve `date` or `date/time` values as string:**

```
<?php
    // Connection
    $server = '127.0.0.1\ikosoft,1066';
    $cinfo = array(
        "ReturnDatesAsStrings"=>true,
        "Database" => "database",
        "UID" => "username",
        "PWD" => "password"
    );
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $cinfo);
    if( $conn === false )
    {
        echo "Error (sqlsrv_connect): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
        exit;
    }

    ....
    // Fetch data
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo  $row['MyDT']."<br>";
    }
    ...
?>
```